# Closure of a singleton

Tags: general-topology

Text: Let $B= ${$(n,n+1): n \in \mathbb{Z}$} $\cup$ {{$k$}:, $k \in \mathbb{Z} $}

Find the closure of {1/2} in the topology generated from $B$

---

Here's my solution:

I got that the closure is $[0, + \infty)$ since its complementar is $(-\infty, 0)$, which is union of open sets $(n,n+1) $

Comment: I edited the text. This is the original

Comment: @drhab It seems to me that that would imply that only $\mathbb{Z}$ is open, but not the singletons $\{n\}\subset \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @MichaelLee Yes, you are right. But things are made clear now.

Comment: The closure of $\{1/2\}$ is going to be the intersection of all closed sets containing $1/2$. Note that $\mathbb{Z}^c$ is closed and contains $1/2$ and that $(n, n+1)^c$ is closed and contains $1/2$ for all $n\neq 0$.

Comment: What do you mean by "topology generated by B"

Comment: @Michael Lee. Ok, so since every complementar set of $(n,n+1)$ (with n!=0)  contains $1/2$, its closure should be $[1, +\infty) $, ?

Comment: No. $[1, \infty)$ doesn't even contain $1/2$. Both of the currently posted answers are correct.

Comment: You did not state which set the topology is on, which makes it impossible to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here $B$ is a *partition* of $\mathbb R$ and consequently the open sets are unions of elements of $B$.

Then the closed sets are automatically also unions of elements of $B$.

This means that in this topology a set is open iff it is closed.

Then the closure of $\{1/2\}$ is set $(0,1)$.

This set is closed an a union of elements of $B$ can only contain $\{1/2\}$ as a subset if it also contains $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

The closure of $\{1/2\}$ will be $(0, 1)$. Note that $$(n, n+1) = \mathbb{Z}^c\cap\left(\bigcap_{k\in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{n\}} (k, k+1)^c\right)$$ is closed and that the points $x_1, x_2\in (n, n+1)$ are topologically indistinguishable, so $1/2$ is topologically indistinguishable from all points in $(0, 1)$, which is closed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess $B$ means for you a basis of open sets, from which is generated the topology we are talking about. If it's a basis of closed sets, the same reasonning is still valid.

Here's my answer : $C = (0,1)$ is the closure of $\{1/2\}$.

To show that result, we must sho two things :

1. $C$ is a closed set.

To show that, we will show that $\complement C = (-\infty, 0] \cup [1, +\infty)$ is an open set : that means that every element of $\complement C$ is contained in an open set itself contained in $\complement C$.

Let $x$ be an element of $\complement C$. There are two subcases :

If $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $x \in \{x\} \subset \complement C$, where $\{x\}$ is an open set because $\{x\} \in B$.

If $x \not\in \mathbb{Z}$, then let $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ be the integral part of $x$. $(n, n+1) \cap C = \varnothing$, thus we have $x \in (n, n+1) \subset \complement C$, where $(n, n+1)$ is an open set because $(n, n+1) \in B$.

2. Any closed set containing $X$ contains $C$.

Let $C'$ be a closed set containing $X$. Let's show that $C \subset C'$ by showing that $\complement C' \subset \complement C$, which are open sets.

Let $x$ be in $(0, 1)$. Any open set containing $x$ contains $(0, 1)$, because it is the least open set containing $x$ in our topology. That means every open set containg $x$ contains $1/2$, and, by taking the contraposition, that any open set that doesn't contain $1/2$ doesn't contain any element of $(0, 1)$ either.

But, $\{1/2\} \subset C'$, so $1/2 \not\in \complement C'$, and so $(0, 1) \cap \complement C' = \varnothing$. We have shown that $\complement C' \subset \complement C$.

This is it. this is my first post here, and I'm french, so I apologize in advance for any mistake I could have made.

Comment: On the "I guess...", I wrote this because a few writers choose to define their topology using a basis of closed sets. If that's what the author meant by "basis", then all occurations of "open" and "closed" should be changed to "closed" and "open" to mean something.